# c# detect new Line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox, newline

I am trying to parse data from the web and separate at the line breaks; however indexof("\n") is not catching it, but the richTextBox shows everything on a separate line.  What am I doing wrong?

string substr = substr.Substring(substr.IndexOf("\n"));

Comment: '*indexof("\n") is not catching it*' is it returning -1 or the wrong value?

Comment: As in how would I do that?

Comment: Not catching the new line

Comment: could you post what you are trying to parse? (or snippet at least)

Comment: http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=10d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=IBM

Comment: That looks a lot like a csv file, you may wish to save your self some effort and look into parsing that instead, (such as streamreader readline and comma split at the very least)

Comment: How do I do that?  I have this streamreader: 


`string url = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=" + period + "&p=" + days + "d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=" + ticker;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            textBox_Ticker.Text = url;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
string url = "google.com/finance/getprices?i="; 
     + period + "&p=" 
      + days + "d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=" + ticker; 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
textBox_Ticker.Text = url; 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
string data = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
sr.Close();
```

Now, I'm going to focus on the last 3 lines here and use them in the following way instead

```
var lines = new List<string>();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseSteam())
{
   while((var line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       lines.Add(line);
   } 
}
```

Note: this is untested and off top of my head

Answer (score 4):

why not just use

```
String.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

and read it into an array? That will "separate it at line breaks" like you want

Comment: Did you assign it to a string array?

Comment: string[] lines = substr.Split(System.Environment.NewLine);

Still has an error "The Best Overload Match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: give the changes a try

Comment: @jister: What about `string[] lines = substr.Split();` with empty arguments? This will use any whitespace as its delimiter. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.

```
string toEmail ='your string here'    
var lstToEmail = toEmail.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```